# Mex Callback function calling matlab function crashed

Tags: matlab, mfc, callback, mex

I have a mex function which tries to transfer the image data of the CCD to the matlab in real time. In order to achieve that, I have to call matlab function in the image data callback function to transfer the image data to the matlab.

This is my entry mex function that registers a callback function which is `snapThreadCallback()` to get the image data.

```
void continousSnapOnChoosed(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) {
    x = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1, mxREAL); 
    double *A = mxGetPr(x);
    A[0] = 50;

    setMaxResolution();//设置为最大分辨率
    HVSTATUS status = STATUS_OK;

    status = HVOpenSnap(hhv, snapThreadCallback, hWnd); 
    mexPrintf("1:%d\n",status);

    m_pRawBuffer = new BYTE[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    m_pImageBuffer = new BYTE[WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3];
    BYTE *ppBuf[1];
    ppBuf[0] = m_pRawBuffer;
    status = HVStartSnap(hhv, ppBuf,1);
    mexPrintf("2:%d\n",status);
}

int CALLBACK snapThreadCallback(HV_SNAP_INFO *pInfo)
{
    int i,j,z;
    ConvertBayer2Rgb(m_pImageBuffer,m_pRawBuffer,WIDTH,HEIGHT,ConvertType,pLutR,pLutG,pLutB,true,layout);

    mwSize ndim = 3;
    mwSize dims[3] = {HEIGHT,WIDTH,3};

    mxArray *OUTArray;
    OUTArray = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim,dims,mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);

    unsigned char *A;
    A = (unsigned char *)mxGetData(OUTArray);

    for (i = 0;i < WIDTH;i++) {
        for (j = 0;j < HEIGHT;j++) {
            for (z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                A[(2 - z) * WIDTH * HEIGHT + i * HEIGHT + HEIGHT - j] = m_pImageBuffer[j * WIDTH * 3 + i * 3 + z];
        }
    }
    mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,1, &OUTArray, "matlab_function");

    return 1;
}
```

In my matlab side, I simply display the image by the given data.

```
function matlab_function(data)
    disp(data);
end
```

However, when I start open the snapshot, The matlab crashed instantly. I later found out that if I comment the `mexCallMATLAB`. The matlab won't crash, and I'm sure there is nothing wrong with how I handle the DLL of the CCD. Because I'm already able to shoot a single frame picture and display it in the matlab.

There is little reference that I can take as examples, since this involves mex file and callback function. I will really appreciate if someone could solve my problem.

At last, I solved the problem by sending message in my callback function and pass the image data in the corresponding message function. It seems like the problem is the memory structure in the callback function is different than the memory structure in the normal C function. However I don't know how difference they are.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing of `A` appears to be wrong.  Instead of

```
A[(2 - z) * WIDTH * HEIGHT + i * HEIGHT + HEIGHT - j] = ...
```

the indexing should be

`A[(2 - z) * WIDTH * HEIGHT + i * HEIGHT + HEIGHT - 1 - j] = ...`

Think about when `z=2`, `i=0`, and `j=0`, the result would have been `A[HEIGHT]` but you want `A[HEIGHT-1]`. But the buffer overrun comes when `z=0`, `i=WIDTH-1` and `j=HEIGHT-1`.

Comment: Thanks,but that's not the problem though. Even if I only call mexCallMATLAB with simply test data in snapThreadCallback method without any image data, it still crash.

Comment: @DavidHx Just to clarify, how do you call this from MATLAB? I mean, MATLAB expects the MEX entry to be `mexFunction`. Did you change that somehow?

Comment: I call this in my mexFunction, This is just a sub function of the entire CCD control

Comment: @DavidHx I see. What does the `CALLBACK` API expand to? By the way, have you seen this part of the `mexCallMATLAB` docs: "Error Handling: If `functionName` detects an error, MATLAB terminates the MEX-file and returns control to the MATLAB prompt. If you want to trap errors, use the `mexCallMATLABWithTrap` function."

Comment: The CALLBACK API is the callback function from the CCD DLL, it will automatically update the m_pRawBuffer, So All I need to do is to give matlab image data updated. Thanks for the advice, I wiil see if I can trap the error

Comment: @DavidHx Were you able to trap the error with `mexCallMATLABWithTrap` or otherwise solve the problem?  If trapping it helped, I'd update my answer. Feel free to upvote if I've helped at all. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't trap the error, but solved the problem by my own method. See my updated post for the reason. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass `NULL` for `plhs` when calling `mexCallMatlab`, because even if you're calling a Matlab function with zero explicit output variables, it might still return an implicit one. (This is the one that gets stored in `ans` or output to the desktop if you're working interactively in the IDE.). Allocate a one-long mxArray and pass it in to `plhs`.